# How to attach a signal to a slot for an object created dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I currently have multiple checkboxes that are created dynamically how can I asssign signal to them.These checkboxes are attached to a  `QStandardItemModel`. I need to know when they are clicked.This is how i am creating checkboxex

```
QStandardItem* chk_all = new QStandardItem();
chk_all->setCheckable(true);
chk_all->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
```

To attach a signal to a slot you need the address of  the sender which is the object. Since the object does not exist in the ui at design time how do i gets its address. So that i could complete the connect statement

```
QObject::connect("what goes here" ,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(CheckClicked())); //Tester
```

Comment: You don't actually assign signals. You connect signals to slots. Did you already read the Qt's documentation about [signal and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/signalsandslots.html) and [connect()-function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#connect)?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question

Comment: just updated my question - hope that clarifies it

Comment: Isn't `chk_all` exactly the pointer (i.e. holds the address) to the object whose signal you want to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These checkboxes are not widgets or separate objects and the `QStandardItem` class doesn't derive from `QObject`, you can't connect each of them individually to a slot.

Since their state is stored in the model, checking or unchecking them will make the model emit the signals `dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)` and `itemChanged(QStandardItem*)`.

But these signals are also emitted for changes other than the checkbox state. You might have to store the checkbox previous state in the model as well  (with `QStandardItem::setData`/`data` and a [custom data role](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)) to be able to compare it to the new state and detect a change.